# Rewriting href in vanilla JS for all <a> objects that begin with a specific ID

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to append a parameter to the URLs of a number of items in a menu using vanilla JS (no jQuery etc).

All of the menu items that I want to play with have one thing in common and I assume this is key to selecting the right objects: They all **begin with** the same ID.

So what I have looks like this:

```
<a href="someplace.php" id="actionMenu123">Link 1</a>
<a href="someplace2.php" id="actionMenu456">Link 2</a>
<a href="someplace3.php" id="actionMenu789">Link 3</a>
<a href="someplace4.php" id="actionMenuABV">Link 4</a>
<a href="someplace5.php" id="actionMenu5X4">Link 5</a>
```

And the JS script that I need should result in the following:

```
<a href="someplace.php?John=Doe" id="actionMenu123">Link 1</a>
<a href="someplace2.php?John=Doe" id="actionMenu456">Link 2</a>
<a href="someplace3.php?John=Doe" id="actionMenu789">Link 3</a>
<a href="someplace4.php?John=Doe" id="actionMenuABV">Link 4</a>
<a href="someplace5.php?John=Doe" id="actionMenu5X4">Link 5</a>
```

I tried to rewrite the hrefs by selecting all `<a>` objects that contain "actionMenu" in their DOM by using querySelectorAll but I don't think I'm doing it right.

I'd be grateful for any pointers.

Comment: So show what you're doing that you think isn't right. CSS-style selectors let you select elements that have an attribute and that have an attribute (like `href`) with a value starting with a given string (like your `id` starting with `actionMenu`. So just use those?

Comment: Well, I guess to avoid having you taken down a less than optimal path: `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("a[href][id^=actionMenu]")).forEach(function (el) {el.search="John=Doe"})` You can patch `Array.from` into older browsers... or if you're using an ES6 transpiler, you could do this instead: `for (let el of document.querySelectorAll("a[href][id^=actionMenu]")) { el=>el.search="John=Doe" }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// first, get list of all 'a' tags and convert to array
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('a'))

  // filter for ones whose id matches. We also want to make
  // sure it *has* an id and an href
  .filter(node => node.id && node.href && node.id.match(/^actionmenu/i))

  // rewrite the href
  .forEach(node => node.href = node.href + '?John=Doe');
```

Comment: Why not just use the available selector engine instead of a `filter`? Also, you can set the `.search` property of the element. Lastly, why use `.map()`? You're discarding the resulting Array.

Comment: @squint because I can't create a selector that complicated without a reference in the minute I get here and there to answer SO questions, but I wrote the above code in about 30 seconds with no references.

Comment: Is being first really so important?

Comment: Works pretty well for me. @squint makes a good point regarding .map() but I don't need the array as I won't be reusing it outside of this context so the solution is fit for purpose. Thanks.

Comment: @squint first, you are absolutely correct about `map` vs `forEach`. Although the language frankly doesn't need both and I have a hard time believing the JIT can't optimize away the unnecessary allocation when the result isn't captured by an assignment. As for the other, you are free to write your own answer which may well be better than mine.

Comment: I usually post comments in lieu of answers in protest to the format of this site. Optimizing away the array creation and population would likely be a simple matter if the implementers could always know what the `.map()` method actually does, but since `Array.prototype` methods can be overwritten I think it would take pretty extensive analysis . And polyfills wouldn't get that benefit either. Then there's the problem for code reviewers seeing the `.map()` result being ignored and needing to double check if it was intentional or not.

Comment: ...at least there's `for-of` now, which IMO is a more compelling replacement for `.forEach`.

Comment: @squint yes, I just *wish* it were first-class. I'm not a big fan of statements.

Comment: A more expression-oriented JS would be nice.

Comment: @squint about the *only* thing I miss from coffeescript. And not badly enough to go back to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting an array of all links starting with "actionMenu"

```
var linkArray = document.querySelectorAll('a[id^=actionMenu]')
```

then loop through the array:

```
for(var i=0; i<linkArray.length; i++) {     
     var newHref = linkArray[i].href + "?John=Doe"; //your new href
     linkArray[i].href = newHref ; //change href
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: There's no need to change the markup, and your code will throw an error because you're reaching text nodes too.